# TabLayout in Navigation Drawer is overlapping the Tolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-tablayout

I have used Navigation Drawer activity and implemented `TabLayout` but when application runs the toolbar is not visible only the tablayout in place of toolbar. But in preview pane toolbar is visible this happens when I run this app on a device. Help me out please

This is `app_bar_main.xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_shopline"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ShopLine"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorShopLineText"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_2sdp"
            />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Here is `content_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

[image: Here is the screen shot]

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" . try setting this line on your toolbar tag

Comment: Could you please share the screen shoot how it seems like?

Comment: Thanks for considering my question, bu it didn't work @Abhishek

Comment: Thanks for considering my question, I have edited the question and added the screen shot @AbdulWaheed

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because of two `AppBarLayout`s you have which android might not recognize the layout you have written.

Simply, remove the other `AppBarLayout` and make your layout like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_shopline" />  

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ShopLine"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorShopLineText"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_2sdp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Acting upon your answer I removed the AppBarLayout from content_main and and implemented your answer in app_bar_main, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the line *"layout_below"*

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
     android:id="@+id/viewpager"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

**android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"**

```
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

Comment: It works when someone adds a `RelativeLayout` otherwise, inside `CoordinatorLayout` it might show that it is useless so would have no effect actually..

Comment: So you can set up style and make it no actionbar so it will allow your custom actionbar.   <style name = "AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

Comment: This is necessary, otherwise the tabLyout over lap the below content